# Projective algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to find a projective algebraic set which is connected but not irreducible? I try to find but stuck at some points if it is not irreducible then it is also not connected

Comment: Consider two hyperplanes, e.g., $(X_1X_2=0)=(X_1=0)\cup(X_2=0)$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add more details about your attempts to your post - this will help you get better, more appropriate answers. You may also wish to peruse the [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) thread on meta, which contains more advice about how to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably worth looking at the notions of connectedness and irreducibility more attentively. A space is not connected if it is a **disjoint** union of two proper closed subsets, while for reducibility it must be a union of **any** proper closed subsets, not necessarily disjoint. So, irreducibility implies connectedness, but there is no implication in the other direction.

As for an example, the one given in a comment to the question (the union of two lines on $\mathbb P^2$) works.

Comment: How can we prove that the union of two lines in P^2 is connected in projective spaces?

Comment: It is not so difficult to describe all closed subsets of this union explicitly. **Hint**: what can you say about closed subsets of one line $\mathbb P^1$?